# JavaEE 6: Can't compile @Resource(lookup="")

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, eclipse-3.5

I am trying to use `@Resource(lookup="")` to look up a resource configured in Glassfish 3.1. I am using Eclipse 3.5.

I've set `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules/endorsed` and added `javax.annotation.jar` to my projects build bath but still it doesn't compile.

I am not able to see the lookup parameter with `@Resource`.

Could someone help me understand why am I not getting the lookup parameter with `@Resource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the `javax.annotation.jar` that you are using is the one for JavaEE6 (and not for a prior version), since `lookup` was introduced in JavaEE 6. Check the MANIFEST of that jar to confirm.

Comment: I got this jar from ${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules/endorsed package and I am using Glassfish 3.1. MANIFEST  says that its been built with jdk 1.6.

Comment: I suggest you see this post - http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2011/02/resource-and-new-lookup-attribute-how.html

Comment: In that post is it not that `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules/endorsed` being set? I am using ant for building my project. But the thing is that I am not able to compile the code in eclipse because I am not getting the correct import, the JavaEE 6 `@Resource` with `lookup` parameter. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you see if you have conflicting jars (perhaps one from JDK and one from Glassfish) for Resource. You could also Ctrl-click on Resource annotation to check which jar it is being picked from.

Comment: The imported `javax.annotation.Resource` did not have the `lookup` attribute so I downloaded `javax.annotation-3.0.1-b19.jar` from http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/javax.annotation/3.0.1-b19/ and made sure that the `javax.annotation.Resource` had the `lookup` element in it using  using `javax.annotation-3.0.1-b19-sources.jar`. Created a folder `endorsed` inside `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib` and copied the `javax.annotation-3.0.1-b19.jar` into it.Then set `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/endorsed`.Do not have anything on the project's build bath. It compiles now.